# Django throws AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta' when trying to migrate

Tags: python, django, migration

I'm working on a small project on my own, and I have some problems with the migrations. I managed to migrate everything well so far, but I removed a field from my `models.py` and now there are problems somehow.

I had a field called `tags` that was referencing to a model from [taggit](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but I decided to remove this field and do it on my own, so the field `tags` still exists but its not referencing to the `tagablemanager` of taggit anymore, but on my own tag model now

Nevermind everytime I excecute `python manage.py migrate` to make the database, this error is thrown:

```
Applying inventory_app.0014_item_tags...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ilianhaesler/Documents/Work/inventory/inventory/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/ilianhaesler/Documents/Work/inventory/inventory/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/ilianhaesler/Documents/Work/inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/ilianhaesler/Documents/Work/inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/ilianhaesler/Documents/Work/inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/ilianhaesler/Documents/Work/inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/ilianhaesler/Documents/Work/inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ilianhaesler/Documents/Work/inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/Users/ilianhaesler/Documents/Work/inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/ilianhaesler/Documents/Work/inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/ilianhaesler/Documents/Work/inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/ilianhaesler/Documents/Work/inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/ilianhaesler/Documents/Work/inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 104, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "/Users/ilianhaesler/Documents/Work/inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 328, in add_field
    if field.many_to_many and field.remote_field.through._meta.auto_created:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

It is referencing to a very old migration file, since I have about 30 migrations so far, and this is from migration 14.

The 14th migration file looks like this:

```
# Generated by Django 4.1 on 2022-09-16 07:34

from django.db import migrations
import taggit.managers


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('inventory_app', '0013_item_gelber_kleber'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='item',
            name='tags',
            field=taggit.managers.TaggableManager(help_text='A comma-separated list of tags.', through='taggit.TaggedItem', to='taggit.Tag', verbose_name='Tags'),
        ),
    ]
```

And this is my model now:

```
class Item(models.Model):

    # Additional Attributes
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="", blank=False, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    


    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Did anyone of you every had a similar problem?

Comment: You still have `taggit` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` right? Or did you remove it?

Comment: Thats the thing, I removed it because I don't need it anymore...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: Migrations depend on removed 3rd-party module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943114/django-migrations-depend-on-removed-3rd-party-module) You can't just directly remove the app from `INSTALLED_APPS`, since your migrations depend on it.

Comment: Thanks this definetely helped a bit. But i'm still confused, because deleting the migration file will cause more problems, since other migration files might have a dependency to this one...